# Floating Action Button On Bottom Left Side. Android

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using a floating action button in my app.

It seems that the normal practice is to place the floating action button in the bottom right of the screen. Most of the examples on the Material Design are like this. (https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html)

I am using google maps in my app, and in the bottom right there are two icons already from google (link to google map, or navigation). I want to put my floating action bar on the bottom left. Is this good practice? I know how to do it, I want to know if it accepted.

Thank you.

Comment: It is your app. You can put any button anywhere you want..!! Coming to the point it is not strictly recommended that you put `FloatingActionButton` on right bottom. You can use it freely..!!

Comment: Yes Agreed with @janki

Answer (score 3):

There isn't anything like it must be displayed on bottom right corner. You can see FAB is displayed in left side in Google IO 2016 android app.

To display FAB on bottom left side:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
```

[image]

Comment: I saw this kind of example, but here the FAB is in the toolbar.

Comment: @AppsMaster9589 did you shared where do you want to display exactly?

Comment: isn't that enough he said `bottom left corner` :P

Answer (score 2):

I'd a similar requirement as yours. I'd to specify `android:layout_alignParentStart` and `android:layout_marginStart` in addition to `android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"` for it to work.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/previous_chapter_fab"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp" />
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding action button is used to direct the user attention on the main action he can perform on that page. By adding more and more buttons, you are not presenting a neat view. Consider, adding few activities to the *side nav bar* which you think might not be the primary thing a user would like to do on your page.
Or you can also **stack** your buttons on the left side itself, something like this
[image]

Or better than that, Use something like **ZOMATO** **+** button which shows more buttons on pressing it
[image: Zomato + button]

**Go through this GitHub repo for Ideas and Code** [Floating Action Button](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)

Answer (score 0):

The Floating Action Button can be placed where you want to on you screen based on the layout and UI you have designed. The main purpose to provide FAB is to give the users instant access to the primary feature/action to be taken on your app or screen.

If you have taken a look at the Material design specifications for FAB, it is mentioned that only one FAB is recommended per screen. However, the specs do not mention the location of the FAB on the screen. It also contain screen shots of apps, where FAB is not placed at bottom-right corner.

https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html

Answer (score -1):

check following xml code it will help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/list_item_movie"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Change from

```
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
```

to

```
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|start"
```